# Finding the "high card" in a poker hand with a regex

Tags: python, regex

Cards in poker are ranked as follows:

```
A>K>Q>J>T>9>8>7>6>5>4>3>2 # Ace, King, Queen, Jack, Ten, 9, ...
```

The current regex I have to find the 'high card' in a hand is as follows:

```
>>> re.search('.*(A|K|Q|J|T|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2)','2Q3AK').group(1)
'K'
```

Is it possible to do the above without so much alternation? I tried writing the 9-2 as `[9-2]`, but it seems character classes need to be ordered ascendingly, in which case it wouldn't properly detect the high card. What would be the proper/best regex for the above example?

Note: the above example is wrong -- the correct answer should be "A" and not "K". Here's an updated attempt:

```
>>> re.search('.*(A)|.*(K)|.*(Q)|.*(J)|.*(T)|.*(9)|.*(8)|.*(7)|.*(6)|.*(5)|.*(4)|.*(3)|.*(2)', '2Q3AK').group(1)
'A'
```

Comment: @Emma that has the same issue as my question, which produces "K" (instead of "A") as the output.

Comment: From all the programs i've seen that use regex, they don't seem to have one for high card: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Poker_hand_analyser#Python

Comment: With `order = 'AKQJT98765432'`, you could simplify the statement by using `str.join`, e.g. `re.search('.*(' + ')|.*('.join(order) + ')').group(1)`, or even use an f-string to put it all in one expression like `re.search(f'.*({")|.*(".join(order)})', '2Q3AK').group(1)`

Comment: Note that your updated regex fails completely if there's no `A` in the hand.

Comment: @Jack -- good point. Why does it fail / what should it be updated to?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 You have a group for each card. So hardcoding `group(1)` will always be populated _only_ if there's an `A` in the hand, and so `K` would be in `group(2)` etc. I would argue that even if you can get regex to do what you want that it's not the right tool for this job. That is, there may be a regex solution, but it's certainly not obvious to me, and to solve the problem I would do something similar to the non-regex answers already provided.

Comment: @Jack, oh I see -- `2Q3KK ==> (None, 'K', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)`. Thanks for the explanation and suggestions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why it's wrong*: the regex

```
re.search('.*(A|K|Q|J|T|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2)','2Q3AK').group(1)
'K'
```

is greedy-matching. It matches as many characters for `.*` as it can, and then spits out the last character:

```
re.search('.*(A|Q|J|T|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|K)','KQ3A2').group(1)
'2'
```

---

As a frame challenge, is there a particular reason you need to use `re` for this? Seems like it would be more explicit and probably easier to understand to just search for the highest-ordered character:

```
order = 'AKQJT98765432'
hand = '2Q3AK'
highest = min(hand, key=order.index)
```

Comment: right but the second part of the question gives a correct answer.

Comment: the `min` approach is very clean, though I'm trying to see what it would translate to if written as a regex / outside of python.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, other non-regex methods, would be also worth looking into, such as using `Counter` or `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

l = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'T', 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

string = '2Q3AK'

c = Counter(string)

for i in l:
    if i in c:
        print(i)
        break
```

#### Output

```
A
```

It is as fast as regex, if that'd be a concern, and it can be as elegant as that too.

Comment: in that case could just do: `>>> min('2Q3AK', key='AKQJT98765432'.index) A`